# Rejected gated check-in (old vb.net Website)

Tags: .net, vb.net, tfs, tfsbuild

I have an old vb.net Website that targets .NET Framework 2.0. When I build and run the project locally, everything works fine. When I queue a build on the tfs I get the following error:

> ~\Website.metaproj: .NET Framework v3.5 Service Pack 1 was not found. In order to target ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0", .NET Framework v3.5 Service Pack 1 or later must be installed.

When I change the target framework to 4 or 4.5 I get the following error:

> ASPNETCOMPILER: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install .net 3.5 on your build server.

Comment: It has 4.5.1 installed. Is it not backwards compatible?

Comment: They are side by side installs

Comment: I accepted your answer. Can you speculate why I get the last error message though (the one with aspnetcompiler)?

Comment: Because it is a 2.0 project and has some code that can't just be compiled in a newer version.